# multiple choice quiz- adding up score

Tags: button

so my intention is to build a quiz on visual basic it is a multiple choice quiz,
i am using 4 buttons as the answer so what I want to do is if they click the correct answer it adds 1 to the score but if they click the wrong button it doesn't add anything. I'm going to be using like 5 questions per level and there are 5 levels and I am going to display the total after they have answered on separate form at the end. Does anyone know how I would go about doing all this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, on the questions if you've got it advancing to the next stage I imagine you have a method to determine whether the answer that they are inputting is correct? If I am right, then this should be pretty simple to do.

You want to declare total score as a variable, this will store the overall score.
To do this you can go like...

```
Dim totalscore As Integer 
totalscore = "0"
```

It is important to set the score on the startup.

Now on the process when you click the correct answer you want to just put a simple statement like

```
totalscore = totalscore + 1
```

This'll add 1 to the score when they advance. You can implement this anyway you like for example you can say

```
If correctanswer.checked = true then 
      totalscore = totalscore + 1
End If
```

Let me know how you get on